How to assign specific testpoints (Test Cases) to a Testrun in Azure Devops / Azure Test Case Management
We run our regression tests via Datadog. There is a lot of copying and pasting for screenshots, assertions on Order API validation etc.. So Im looking into integrating Datadog with Azure Test Case Manager for less manual work during regression. I feel like Im almost at a got MVP/Proof to show my manager but I cant wrap my head around Testcases(Test Points) not being able to be assigned to a test run.
Here is my Dilemma.
I have a bunch of tests in Datadog.
At the beginning of each test, I set the corresponding tests in TCM to "FAILED" to start the new regression cycle via this PATCH
https://dev.azure.com/{{orgID}}/{TeamId}}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{{PlanID}}/Suites/{{SuiteID}}/TestPoint?api-version=7.1-preview.2
Im able to change the Test Case at the Test point with no issues.
My test runs and completes, and then I call that same PATCH again, but this time, I set the status to "Passed."
Great right? But here in comes my Dilemma. Every time I make a call to update that Testcase/TestPoint it creates a new TestRun. We have over 100 test cases we run weekly.. it could get really convulated very soon.
I have figured out how to create a test run via the CreatTestRun API Call
https://dev.azure.com/{{orgID}}/{{TeamID}}/_apis/test/runs/1050847?api-version=5.0
but I cant associate my PATCH with a runID.. Is there something Im missing? Am I going about this in the wrong way? ANy Help would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @ThatBraziliann, Good day. Have you got a chance to check the answer below to use test/runs and testresults APIs to create and update test runs? Hope it can work from your side as well. Thx for the sharing and efforts.

We can use this API to GET the test points of a test suite. Each test point is mapping to a test case defined under that test suite.
If we use API to update some or all of the test points in a test suite and set the test point outcome(s) as no matter Failed or Passed, it will generate a new test run with an incremental runId.
As far as I understand based on your description, if you would expect to reset the test outcomes, you should set the test points as Active, which will not generate any test run. Then you may rerun those tests to generate a new test run for a new regression cycle. You may review if you have to manually update test point outcome(s), since that operation will create additional runs.
Here is a sample request to reset test outcome for your reference.
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/TestPoint?api-version=7.1-preview.2

[
    {  
        "id":245,
        "isActive":true
    },
    {
        "id":307,
        "isActive":true
    }
]

In addition, you may use this API to create a test run with test point(s)
POST https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=7.1

{
  "name": "NewTestRun1",
  "plan": {
    "id": "2"
  },
  "pointIds": [
    245
  ]
}


You may use this API to add new test cases(test points) for a test run.
POST https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testresults/runs/${newTestRunId}/results?api-version=7.1-preview.2

[
    {
        "configuration": {
            "id":  "1",
            name: "Windows 10"
        },
        "testCase":  {
            "id":  "5",
            "name":  "Test Case 2"
        },
        "testPoint":  {
            "id":  "307"
        },
        "priority":  2,
        "testCaseTitle":  "Test Case 2",
        "testCaseRevision": 4,
        "testPlan":  {
        "id":  "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "configuration": {
            "id":  "1",
            name: "Windows 10"
        },
        "testCase":  {
            "id":  "6",
            "name":  "Test Case 3"
        },
        "testPoint":  {
            "id":  "308"
        },
        "priority":  2,
        "testCaseTitle":  "Test Case 3",
        "testCaseRevision": 2,
        "testPlan":  {
        "id":  "2"
        }
    }
]

And use this API to update each test result for individual test case(test point) of this test run.
PATCH https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testresults/runs/${newTestRunId}/results?api-version=7.1-preview.2

[
    {  
        "id":  100001,
        "outcome": "Passed",
        "state": "Completed",
        "configuration": {
            "id":  "1",
            name: "Windows 10"
        },
        "testCase":  {
            "id":  "5",
            "name":  "Test Case 2"
        },
        "testPoint":  {
            "id":  "307"
        },
        "priority":  2,
        "testCaseTitle":  "Test Case 2",
        "testCaseRevision": 4,
        "testPlan":  {
        "id":  "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id":  100002,
        "outcome": "Failed",
        "configuration": {
            "id":  "1",
            name: "Windows 10"
        },
        "testCase":  {
            "id":  "6",
            "name":  "Test Case 3"
        },
        "testPoint":  {
            "id":  "308"
        },
        "priority":  2,
        "testCaseTitle":  "Test Case 3",
        "testCaseRevision": 2,
        "testPlan":  {
        "id":  "2"
        }
    }
]



